# Angular Fire: undefined is not a function ($on method does not exist)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to log my Firebase data to the console. But I keep getting an error of `undefined is not a function`. Full error below:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.childAdded (http://localhost:9000/scripts/services/ProviderService.js:11:22)
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/main.js:118:19)
```

This is what my code currently looks like:

**ProviderService.js**

```
angular.module('outcomesApp').service('ProviderService', function(FBURL, $q, $firebase) {
  var providerRef = new Firebase(FBURL).child('providers');
  var fireProvider = $firebase(providerRef).$asArray();

  return {
    childAdded: function childAdded(cb) {
      fireProvider.$on('child_added', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    },
    ...
```

**main.js**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $filter, $timeout, $firebase, FBURL, ProviderService) {
  ProviderService.childAdded(function(addedChild) {
    $scope.providers.push(addedChild);
  });
  ...
```

The error is occurring on this line: `fireProvider.$on('child_added', function(data) {`

Comment: I am not sure this is how you return function in a `.service`.

Comment: @Blazemonger Well it's defined in `ProviderService`, which I've injected into my `MainCtrl`...

Comment: At first glance, it looks like `fireProvider.$on` is not a function. Can you confirm if it is?

Comment: @Mutahhir How can I confirm this? I've been following a tutorial to do this and they've changed `providerRef.on` (which worked) to `fireProvider.$on` (which throws an error).

Comment: Just adding a breakpoint on childAdded function and then using the browser dev tools console and type in `fireProvider.$on` and `fireProvider.on`. The result will let you know.

Comment: @Mutahhir I've done that and both are returning as `undefined`...

Comment: Why don't you add a  $watch on fireProvider route on service initialize and $emit or $broadcast an event from your `ProviderService` instead when the $watch is triggered? I not familiar with AngularFire, but I think they support $watch and if you can't get $on and on to work, you can roll your own easily.

Comment: @DavidEast I'm using this tutorial (http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/real-time-web-apps-with-angularjs-and-firebase), and I'm trying to log my data in the console, as seen in this gif (http://cl.ly/YtBK).

Comment: That would be my tutorial. The AngularFire version is way outdated now. See my answer. I'm thinking about making an updated one.

Answer (score 4):

You're using an outdated version of AngularFire. That version looks like 0.7 and since 0.8, there has been a lot of changes. The `.$on` method no longer exists, so that's why you're receiving the undefined error. Now with the new version of Firebase you can refactor your code to just a few short lines using the new API.

When needing to manage a collection, use the new `.$asArray()` method.

With the 0.8 update, `.$on()` has been removed and replaced with using either `.$asArray()` or `.$asObject`.

Previously we'd have to use `.$on()` to listen to children being added to the collection. Now using `.$asArray()` we get automatic updates to a collection.

```
angular.module('example').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $firebase) {
  var ref = new Firebase('<your-firebase>');

  // using $asArray we automatically have child_added handled for us
  $scope.items = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
});
```

You can easily put this data in a Factory as well.

```
angular.module('example').factory('Items', function($firebase) {
  var ref = new Firebase('<your-firebase>');
  return $firebase(ref).$asArray();
});

angular.module('example').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Items) {
  $scope.items = Items;
});
```

Comment: So would you recommend upgrading my version of AngularFire and refactoring the code using the `.$asArray()` method? I'm trying to get the Prev and Next buttons working, from your tutorial. I'm using the `.$asArray()` on my `fireProvider`variable. Would I jut remove the `$on` completely?

Comment: I don't get it. How do I listen to `child_added` then? To use `watch`? I was just on firebase meetup and guy told me not to use `watch` cause it's very intensive and watches all elements. How can I listen only to `child_added` changes to my `firebaseArray` since the `$on` is deprecated?

Comment: A $firebaseArray is an array that has all of the appropriate (child_added, child_changed, child_removed, child_removed) listeners attached to it. You simply bind it to scope and call it a day. AngularFire will handle the rest.

Comment: Let me know if my answered work for you. If so please mark it as accepted. It's good to keep the unanswered queue clear.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get promise data?, I don't know much about firebase, let's try this. You have $q but not being used. If this throw error, it has to do with the service provider.

```
function providerReference(){
var deferred = $q.defer(),
providerRef = new Firebase(FBURL).child('providers');
providerRef.then(function(d) {
    var fireProvider = $firebase(d).$asArray();
    deferred.resolve(fireProvider);
}, function(err) {
    console.log('error')
});
return deferred.promise
```

}

```
return {
 childAdded: function() {
     return providerReference();
 }
```

}

In main.js

```
$scope.providers = [];
ProviderService.childAdded().then(function(addedChild) {
    $scope.providers.push(addedChild);
})
```